# Is it the same meaning "what is wrong" vs "what is it wrong"?

Tags: grammar

Is it the same meaning "what is wrong" vs "what is it wrong"?
if it isn't the same, please give me some example sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do not have the same meaning.  "What is it wrong?" is simply ungrammatical, and incorrect English.  "What is it wrong?" has no meaning.

You could correct this sentence to say "What is it *that is* wrong?" which would have a similar meaning to "What is wrong?"  The difference would be that adding more words makes the statement much more formal, stiff, and perhaps a feeling of pretension depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase, "what is it wrong" is grammatically incorrect. I'm presuming you are referring to the phrase "what is wrong *with* it".

If so, then I see no major difference in their meaning except for the fact that the latter phrase is referring to a certain subject ("it"). In a sense, it is more specific than merely saying "what is wrong", which gives off a rather general question and/or feeling.